# Strange Combobox behaviour when binding text property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

If we have a combobox bound 'twoway' to a TimeSpan property on a view model, and a converter changing the timespan view model property to a string, adding a 'm' for minutes, then when editing the combobox value from say 10m to 5, I would expect:

WPF Binding calls ConvertBack to get value to update source property - let's assume that is a timespan for 5 minutes.

The view model's timespan property setter is called and sets the underlying field (changing from timespan of 10 to 5) and then raises OnPropertyChanged

WPF Binding receives event and therefore calls its handler method, which first does a Convert for the value, and then sets this '5m' converted value to the target text property

Except, the last step does not happen, and the comboxbox remains at 5. I actually want this behaviour, but would like to understand why the last step does not happen. Strange thing is changing to a textbox does give the behaviour I expect (updating 5 to 5m immediately)

EDIT: original question mistakenly stated textbox where I should have written combobox

UPDATE: using the snoop utility, I see that the text property of combobox does become 5m, but display remains 5 - I can only assume if the combobox is being edited, it does not refresh its text display. Changed title of question from "WPF Data Binding Target-Source-Target cycle using converter" to more accurately reflect what it now is.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show your sample code where you are facing this issue because this sample code works for me -

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

**Property**

```
public TimeSpan Time
{
   get
   {
      return time;
   }
   set
   {
      if (time != value)
      {
         time = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Time");
      }
   }
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is TimeSpan)
            {
                return ((TimeSpan)value).Minutes.ToString() + "m";
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                return new TimeSpan(0, System.Convert.ToInt32(value), 0);
            }
            return new TimeSpan();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks very much - I had actually changed to a combobox and got the behaviour described (sorry should have stated this, for some reason I had textbox in my brain); changing back to a textbox gives the same behaviour as your code (and my code is pretty much the same as yours). Any idea why a combobox would behave differently?

    <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

Answer (score 0):

ConvertBack method of the converter will only set the value of Binding source property, then your target property (i.e Text of ypur TextBox) would not be updated.If it would be so then there would be infinite loop everytime when the bindingmode of the binding would be TwoWay.Convert Method is called when there is change in source property and ConvertBack  is called when there is change in the target property of the binding. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks - I thought the 'infinite loop' is avoided by a check to see if the property value has changed, before updating the target or source. This is a twoway binding, and my question is really about the convert method not updating the target.